# При double клике tab панель исчезает

Tags: jquery, css

Здравсвуйте.

При тесте **tab панели** наткнулсья на такую проблему.

> При двойном клике на **панель и на блок текста** тоже панель изчезает и опять показывается сразу.

Я поставил вниз панелья footer что бы вам ясно было понятно почему нужно решить данную задачку.(А то некоторые могут подумать что исчезает и сразу появляется что тут может быть плохого)Помогите пожалуйста что может быть не так ?

```js
// TABS AFFIX
 // tabbed content

    $(".main_content").hide();
    $(".main_content:first").show();

  /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs_container li").click(function() {
    
      $(".main_content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();    
    
      $("ul.tabs_container li").removeClass("active_content");
      $(this).addClass("active_content");

    $(".tab_drawer_heading_main").removeClass("d_active");
    $(".tab_drawer_heading_main[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
    
    });
  /* if in drawer mode */
  $(".tab_drawer_heading_main").click(function() {
      
      $(".main_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
    
    $(".tab_drawer_heading_main").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");
    
    $("ul.tabs_container li").removeClass("active_content");
    $("ul.tabs_container li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active_content");
    });
  $('ul.tabs_container li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
.filterlist_main {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 color: #37454d;
 direction: ltr;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs_container {
 width: 250px;
 display: flex;
 table-layout: fixed;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 32px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
    border-top: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
    border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}
ul.tabs_container li {
 
 width: 250px;
 display: flex;
 table-layout: fixed;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 32px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
    border-top: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
    border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs_container li:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
 color: #333;
}
ul.tabs_container li.active_content {
 border-bottom-color:#37454d;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
 display: block;
}
ul.tabs_container .tabs-item.active_content {
 border-bottom-color:#37454d;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
 display: block;
}
.tab_main_container {
 border-top: none;
 /*border: 1px solid #333;*/
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: auto;
}
.main_content {
 padding: 20px;
 display: none;
}
.tab_drawer_heading_main {
 display: block;
}

ul.tabs_container li:first-child {
    cursor:auto;
}
ul.tabs_container li:first-child:hover {
    cursor:auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    color:  #697379;
}
.tab_last { border-right: 1px solid #333; }
.footer {
  height:400px;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-affix filterlist_main">
  <ul class="tabs_container">
    <span style="text-indent: 1em;line-height: 2;">Сортировать:</span>
    <li class="tabs-item active_content" rel="tab4">
      <button class="tabs-label">Our recommendations</button>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs-item" rel="tab5">
      <button class="tabs-label">Distance from city center</button>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs-item" rel="tab6">
      <button class="tabs-label">Rating based on reviews</button>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs-item" rel="tab7">
      <button class="tabs-label">Lowest price first</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="tab_main_container">
    <div class="center_content d_active tab_drawer_heading_main" rel="tab4">
      <div id="tab4" class="container_itemlist main_content" >
        fulpix
        <!-- BURA ATILACAG TEKST VAR -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tab 4 -->
    <div class="center_content active_content tab_drawer_heading_main" rel="tab5">
      <div class="container_itemlist main_content" id="tab5">
        chermander
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tab 5-->
    <div class="center_content active_content tab_drawer_heading_main" rel="tab6">
      <div class="container_itemlist main_content" id="tab6">
        bulbasaur
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tab 6-->
    <div class="center_content active_content tab_drawer_heading_main" rel="tab7">
      <div class="container_itemlist main_content" id="tab7">
        pikachu
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tab 7-->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
kakoy nibud footter
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема кроется в вашем `fadeIn();` Суть получается примерно следующая - сам блок вы скрываете сразу, а вот `fadeIn` сперва меняет `opacity` и затем уже только делает блок видимым. Вот и получается. Чтоб избежать этого и иметь этот эффект - лучше использовать `animate()` - сперва делаете у всех `main_content` `opacity 0`, затем скрываете их и тут же показываете какой нужный (он все еще прозрачный) и затем уже опять с помощью `animate` убираете прозрачность

```js
// TABS AFFIX
 // tabbed content

    $(".main_content").hide();
    $(".main_content").css({opacity: 0});    
    $(".main_content:first").show();  
    $(".main_content:first").css({opacity: 1});

  /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs_container li:not(.clicked)").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      $.each($('ul.tabs_container li:not([rel="'+$(this).attr('rel')+'"])'), function(){
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');;
      })
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
      //$(".main_content").animate({opacity:0}, 300, function(){
        $(".main_content").hide(); 
        $("#"+activeTab).show();
        $("#"+activeTab).animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
      //});
    
      $("ul.tabs_container li").removeClass("active_content");
      $(this).addClass("active_content");

    $(".tab_drawer_heading_main").removeClass("d_active");
    $(".tab_drawer_heading_main[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
    
    });
  /* if in drawer mode */
  $(".tab_drawer_heading_main").click(function() {
      
      $(".main_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
    
    $(".tab_drawer_heading_main").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");
    
    $("ul.tabs_container li").removeClass("active_content");
    $("ul.tabs_container li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active_content");
    });
  $('ul.tabs_container li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
.filterlist_main {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 color: #37454d;
 direction: ltr;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs_container {
 width: 250px;
 display: flex;
 table-layout: fixed;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 32px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
    border-top: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
    border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}
ul.tabs_container li {
 
 width: 250px;
 display: flex;
 table-layout: fixed;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 32px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
    border-top: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
    border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs_container li:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
 color: #333;
}
ul.tabs_container li.active_content {
 border-bottom-color:#37454d;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
 display: block;
}
ul.tabs_container .tabs-item.active_content {
 border-bottom-color:#37454d;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
 display: block;
}
.tab_main_container {
 border-top: none;
 /*border: 1px solid #333;*/
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: auto;
}
.main_content {
 padding: 20px;
 display: none;
}
.tab_drawer_heading_main {
 display: block;
}

ul.tabs_container li:first-child {
    cursor:auto;
}
ul.tabs_container li:first-child:hover {
    cursor:auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    color:  #697379;
}
.tab_last { border-right: 1px solid #333; }
.footer {
  height:400px;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-affix filterlist_main">
  <ul class="tabs_container">
    <span style="text-indent: 1em;line-height: 2;">Сортировать:</span>
    <li class="tabs-item active_content" rel="tab4">
      <button class="tabs-label">Our recommendations</button>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs-item" rel="tab5">
      <button class="tabs-label">Distance from city center</button>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs-item" rel="tab6">
      <button class="tabs-label">Rating based on reviews</button>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs-item" rel="tab7">
      <button class="tabs-label">Lowest price first</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="tab_main_container">
    <div class="center_content d_active tab_drawer_heading_main" rel="tab4">
      <div id="tab4" class="container_itemlist main_content" >
        fulpix
        <!-- BURA ATILACAG TEKST VAR -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tab 4 -->
    <div class="center_content active_content tab_drawer_heading_main" rel="tab5">
      <div class="container_itemlist main_content" id="tab5">
        chermander
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tab 5-->
    <div class="center_content active_content tab_drawer_heading_main" rel="tab6">
      <div class="container_itemlist main_content" id="tab6">
        bulbasaur
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tab 6-->
    <div class="center_content active_content tab_drawer_heading_main" rel="tab7">
      <div class="container_itemlist main_content" id="tab7">
        pikachu
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tab 7-->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
kakoy nibud footter
</div>
```

Comment: что то выглядит это так же как и у автора, почти

Comment: тут правда футер не прыгает вверх но всеравно текст скрывается у вас.А нужно чтобы не скрывалсья  @Vladimir Novopashin

Comment: @teran А я должен абсолютно весь код свой написать? Баг я поправил, работает как и просили. Не понимаю смысл вашего комментария

Comment: @Избытоксусликов и что мешает просто закомментировать функцию анимации? Или вы вообще код не смотрели? Или то что у вас есть вы тоже не сами писали? Поправил, смотрите сейчас. При нажатии на сам блок не поправлял - ибо делается абсолютно так же, сделаете по аналогии

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin принимаю ваш ответ так как ответ вы поправили и работает уже так как надо спасибо.